# Running a C program from python while taking command line input

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, executable

I am first generating an executable file for a C program using : `gcc mycode.c -o mycode -lm` and getting an executable file named 'mycode'

Now to run that code the format is : `./<exec_file> <filestem_dataset> <result_file_name>`

For an example : `./mycode mydataset myoutfile`

Where mydataset is the name of the stem file which has one .data file and one .names file.

The output will be written to : `myoutfile`

Now I want to write a python code where I will use that `mycode` executable file and in between the python code I need to use `mydayaset.names` once and that `myoutfile` once. And suppose my python program name is `first_code.py`. Now I want to run this code using a command line argument say : `python3 first_code.py mydataset`

I am trying as :

```
import re
import os
import sys

dataset = sys.argv[1]

os.system(f"/home/dev/mycode -u -f {dataset}")

file1 = open(dataset+".names", 'r')
```

Then when I am executing this using `python3 first_code.py mydataset` it is still giving the C files command that how I need to write that is : `./<exec_file> <filestem_dataset> <result_file_name>`

And one more thing I also need to use that myoutfile inside this python code as well. For now I am reading that file as : `file2 = open('myoutfile', 'r')` So it is reading from the already compiled and generated myoutfile file for a particular stem file but I want that in general. That is I just want to give : `python3 first_code.py mydataset` in the terminal.

Edit1 : One more point I want to add, if I write

```
os.system(f"/home/dev/mycode -u -f {dataset} > Tempfile")
```

Then that Tempfile is having a line saying : `./<exec_file> <filestem_dataset> <result_file_name>`

Edit2 : Inside my C program where I am counting the number of arguments given I have written an if condition as :

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    char filename[100];
    if(argc!=3){
        printf("\n./<exec_file> <filestem_dataset> <result_file_name>\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: In `somecommand > Tempfile`, `> Tempfile` is an instruction to the shell to make stdout be opened to a write handle on `Tempfile` before running `somecommand`; it **is not** an argument so `somecommand`, so it doesn't show up in `argv` and `argc` doesn't count it.

Comment: Anyhow -- if `mycode` has the `main()` you show, and you want it to write output to a file in the current directory named `Tempfile`, then it would need to be called as something like `subprocess.run(['/home/dev/mycode', dataset, 'Tempfile'])`. I don't know where you're getting `-u` or `-f` from.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I got it. Can you please refer me some resources to learn python in an effective manner but a little quickly as I belong from different stream, currently trying to learn python and C both for a project. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I personally learned Python just from the https://docs.python.org documentation.